# Switch case para comparar cadenas

Tags: c++, dev-c++, condiciones, string

Tengo una duda sobre el uso de la estructura de control `switch` ya que apenas voy aprendiendo C++. ¿Se puede evaluar cadenas de catacteres en un `switch`? Según yo solo se pueden valores enteros:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int mes;
cout<<"Ingresa las primeras tres letras del mes que desee\n";
cin>>mes;
switch (mes)
{
    case 'ene':
        {       
    cout<<"El nombre del mes es enero\n ";
    break;
}
case 'feb':
    {
    cout<<"El nombre del mes es febrero\n";
    break;
}
    case 'mar':
        {       
    cout<<"El nombre del mes es marzo\n ";
    break;
}
    case 'abr':
        {       
    cout<<"El nombre del mes es abril\n ";
    break;
}
    case 'may':
        {       
    cout<<"El nombre del mes es mayo\n ";
    break;
}
    case 'jun':
        {       
    cout<<"El nombre del mes es junio\n ";
    break;
}
    case 'jul':
        {       
    cout<<"El nombre del mes es julio\n ";
    break;
}
    case 'ago':
        {       
    cout<<"El nombre del mes es agosto\n ";
    break;
}
    case 'sep':
        {       
    cout<<"El nombre del mes es septiembre\n ";
    break;
}
    case 'oct':
        {       
    cout<<"El nombre del mes es octubre\n ";
    break;
}
    case 'nov':
        {       
    cout<<"El nombre del mes es noviembre\n ";
    break;
}
    case 'dic':
        {       
    cout<<"El nombre del mes es diciembre\n ";
    break;
}
default:
cout<<"No es un mes";
}
system ("PAUSE");
return(0);
}
```

Comment: no pongas el código como imagen, dale editar pegalo como texto, seleccionalo y da clic en el ícono `{}`

Comment: Si queres evaluar cadenas de texto podes usar varios ifs y en las condiciones usar la funcion strcmp para comparar cadenas de caracteres

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde se no es posible, Tu puedes evaluar con switch a 1 caracter o 1 entero pero No a una cadena de caracteres... Logicamente es un poco imposible a una cadena de caracteres si lo piensas.
En tu caso lo que haria seria que al ingresar por ejemplo 12 me muestre que es diciembre.
Una cosa mas, estas usando una variable de tipo entero para guardar un caracter
Saludos

Comment: no se puede evaluar cadenas en un switch, lo que te conviene hacer es usar varios ifs y utilizar la funcion strcmp para comparar cadenas de texto

Comment: pero strcmp no es una función en C++, así que tampoco recomiendo su uso si vas a hacer código C++

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos ¿ Que `strcmp( )` **no** es una función de C++ ? ¿ Cuando ha pasado eso ? Porque en [cdppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) dice que **si** está, en la cabecera `<string>` O_o

Comment: Me refería a una función no heredada de C, para evitar la confusión entre lenguajes. Y sí, forma parte de C++ "al uso", pero es mejor trabajar con el tipo de dato `std::string` en vez de con `const char *`, que es un dato heredado de C, con lo que conlleva mayores problemas (tales como mezclar lenguajes). De ahí, mi sentencia tan tajante.

Comment: @Trauma `strcmp` no pertenece a la cabecera `<string>`, sino a `<cstring>` lo que en su defecto indica que es una adaptación de su equivalente en C.